# Resharper removes yield from foreach. Why?

Tags: c#, resharper, yield-return

I recently learned about `yield` and then created the following test console program:

```
    public static string Customers = "Paul,Fred,Doug,Mark,Josh";
    public static string Admins = "Paul,Doug,Mark";

    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = CreateEfficientObject();

        Console.WriteLine(test.Admins.FirstOrDefault());
        //Note that 'GetAllCustomers' never runs. 
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        var databaseFetch = Customers.Split(',');
        foreach (var s in databaseFetch)
        {
            yield return s;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetAllAdmins()
    {
        var databaseFetch = Admins.Split(',');
        foreach (var s in databaseFetch)
        {
            yield return s;
        }
    }

    static LoginEntitys CreateEfficientObject()
    {
        var returnObject = new LoginEntitys {};
        returnObject.Admins = GetAllAdmins();
        returnObject.Customers = GetAllCustomers();
        return returnObject;
    }
}
public class LoginEntitys
{
    public IEnumerable<String> Admins { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<String> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Yet I noticed Resharper wants to convert my `foreach` loops to :

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetAllCustomers()
{
    var databaseFetch = Customers.Split(',');
    return databaseFetch;
}
```

Why does Resharper want to remove yield from this case? It changes the functionality completely as it will no longer lazy load without yield. I can only guess that either

- A) I am using `yield` incorrectly/in bad pratice
- B) It's a Resharper bug/suggestion that can just be ignored.

Any insight would be great.

Comment: `Split` is not lazy..

Comment: What function will never run? The point is that there's no reason for your code to be "lazy". The split is done up front. The only bit that's lazy is returning the values.

Comment: Ah, OK - I see now. Yes, it removes deferred execution.

Comment: Not sure why @dasblinkenlight removed his answer. It is correct. There is no benefit of `yield return` in this case.

Comment: @Mrchief He removed it because he recognized that it was incorrect, and that it does in fact alter the behavior of the method.  Whether the altered behavior is better or worse is another matter entirely.

Comment: @Servy: ReSharper alters it because the altered behavior is probably better with lower overhead. I don't think it'll alter any yield return that acts on something that is indeed benefited by lazy loading.

Comment: @Mrchief It is functionally different.  *It doesn't do the same thing*.  If you want the semantics of one, that one is better, if you want the semantics of the other, that one is better.  Making a "performance" improvement that makes a correct program produce an incorrect answer is an invalid change.  The OP is *getting something* for what he's paying.  If he doesn't want that thing that he's getting then sure, he can get rid of it, *but what if he needs it*.

Comment: @Servy: How is he getting incorrect answer? In both cases he'll get the same array elements.

Comment: @Mrchief In this case it's the difference between whether the operation on `Customers` is performed or not.  One could also mutate the `Customers` or `Admins` references after creating the iterators but before iterating them to observe the differences between the two programs more profoundly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60038/discussion-between-mrchief-and-servy).

Comment: As a result in the confusion about how this transformation is actually functionally different, which is really separate from what this question is asking, [I have asked a new question discussing that separate issue with this code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25515373/1159478).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that this proposed transformation changes the functionality of the code in subtle ways, preventing it from deferring the evaluation of the properties and performing the `Split` from being evaluated as early.

Perhaps those that implemented it were well aware that it was a change in functionality and felt that it was still a useful suggestion, one that could be ignored if the existing semantics were important, or if they actually failed to realize that the semantics were being altered.  There's no good way for us to know, we can only guess.  If those semantics are important for your program, then you are correct to not make the suggested transformation.

Comment: My understanding is that the execution is exactly the same since Split() is evaluated immediately (it returns an array after all). No deferred execution is gained via the foreach/yield so you may as well return the `IEnumerable<>` directly as Resharper suggests.

Comment: @itsme86 Then you should run the program yourself to observe the different outputs of the two implementations to see for yourself.

Comment: Maybe you can explain where my logic is flawed. Where is the deferred execution occurring?

Comment: @itsme86 The question isn't asking if the two are the same.  The OP *knows* that they're not the same.  He even wrote the program to prove it.  He's not asking why the two programs function differently; he has given me every reason to believe that he knows exactly why they're different.  He's asking why Resharper is making a transformation that he knows is a functional change.  If you want to know specifically why these code snippets are different, and how, specifically, the differences between these implementations can be observed, feel free to ask that as a new question.

Comment: @itsme86 when you launch the sample I gave the 'GetAllCustomers()' is deferred. Note that in 'Main()' I never call "test.Customers". Thus, because of yield, 'GetAllCustomers()' never executes.

Answer (score 2):

I think Resharper is being a bit dumb here, in the sense that its applying a standard "convert foreach to LINQ" transform without being aware of the context.

It doesn't suggest the same edits for a `while` loop:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLineFromFile(TextReader fileReader)
{
    using (fileReader)
    {
        string currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return currentLine;
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the next iteration of Resharper which uses Roslyn will be much more context aware.

Thanks @servy for an engaging and refreshing discussion!

Comment: Presumably the refactor is only suggested when there is a `foreach(var x in something)yield return x;` *as the last statement of the method*.  In that case the changes are only with respect to how execution is deferred.  The example you gave changes far more than just how execution is deferred, and so it obviously couldn't come close to making such a suggested transformation.  I mean, how would you even suggest altering the code you provided to not use an iterator block?

Comment: @Servy: In general, Resharper will prompt any `foreach` loop to be converted to Linq, even complex, multi statement ones too and it usually does an impressive job at that.

Comment: FYI according to Jetbrains, [Resharper will not use Roslyn in the foreseeable future](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/04/10/resharper-and-roslyn-qa/).

Comment: @PatrickQuirk: Their blog post makes sense. And looks like I misread the last para on [this one](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/07/30/resharper9-first-look-at-csharp6-support/) to presume that.

Comment: @Mrchief If this case resharper isn't translating the `foreach` into LINQ though.  No LINQ is used here.

Comment: @servy: That's the message Resharper shows in the suggested action tooltip - "Convert into a LINQ-expression".

Answer (score -2):

The code in your example is not calling the iterator on the `IEnumerable` you are returning. If you were using the result of `GetAllAdmins()` in a LINQ query for example the `yield` would be useful because execution of the expression could resume on each iteration.

I would imagine Resharper is just suggesting you remove unused code.

Comment: The yield is in use though as it causes 'lazy' loading. Note the method 'GetAllCustomers' will never execute.