# Understanding "possible multiple enumeration" problem

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I saw a video on youtube "How IEnumerable can kill your performance in C#" discussing the "Possible multiple enumeration" issue. Then I made some tests about it but I don't understand how things work.

Have a look to this code:

```
var v = GetLinesLength();
Console.WriteLine(v.FirstOrDefault());
Console.WriteLine(v.FirstOrDefault());

IEnumerable<int> GetLinesLength()
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("con"); //read from stdin 
    foreach (var line in lines)
        yield return line.Length;
}
```

If I run it, the function `GetLinesLength()` is called twice. And that's ok.

But I would expect the same if I modify the function like this...

```
IEnumerable<int> GetLinesLength()
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("con");
    return lines.Select(x => x.Length);
}
```

Why in this case the function is called just once?

Comment: In the first case the results is an enumerator not a real list. An enumerator is enumerated everytime you want to loop over it. That happens when you call FirstOrDefault and it gets called twice but only the first iteration of the foreach in the method is done. Because of the enumerator it can break out early as the method is only interested in the first element. The second one creates a real list and that gets directly created and attached to v and for a real list the functions does not need to be executed again you already have the list.

Comment: You might want to debug your code and have a look at the actual type of v in your 2 variants of GetLinesLength

Comment: @Ralf: actually the second one is not "creating a real list" but also a lazy `IEnumerable<int>`. But the difference is that this will execute only the `lines.Select(x => x.Length)` again and again and not the whole method. If you want to process the result of the method multiple times "materialize" the query to a collection by adding `ToList`/`ToArray` or by storing the single item you are interested in into a variable, like `int firstLength = GetLinesLength.FirstOrDefault()`. The advantage of the enumerator is that you always get the current state, so if someone modifies the file.

Comment: This goes to my premise "stop using var when things get tricky/unclear at all".

Comment: @granadaCoder it would not change anything if he had written `IEnumerable<int>` instead of var

Comment: This is more or less the same as what's in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515373/how-is-transforming-this-iterator-block-a-functional-change) with just a few tweaks.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thats more correct yes.